# Query on Oracle to eliminate 0 quantity

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the next query, and sometimes for same id, clients and name I get a market value with a quantity and another market value with quantity 0. How can I modify the query to get only the market value with quantity and not the quantity 0 ?

```
SELECT p.ID_CLIENT, p.CLIENT, p.NAME, h.MARKET_VALUE
FROM HOLDING h
INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO p ON h.PF_ID = p.PF_ID 
WHERE
    TO_CHAR (h.DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = ? 
    AND NVL (p.PF_ID, '') = ? 
    AND NVL (h.TYPE, '') NOT IN 'Master'
    AND NVL (h.INSTRUMENT, '') NOT IN 'FX'
```

The output I have now is :

```
ID_CLIENT   CLIENT  NAME    MARKET_VALUE
207        Momentum AAA 0
207        Momentum AAA 3514.11
207        Momentum BBB 0
207        Momentum CCC 84289.84
207        Momentum CCC 358.74
```

And what I want is:

```
ID_CLIENT   CLIENT  NAME    MARKET_VALUE
207        Momentum AAA 3514.11
207        Momentum BBB 0
207        Momentum CCC 84289.84
207        Momentum CCC 358.74
```

Comment: Your query has no column named `quantity` (note:  I didn't downvote).  Also, the `IN`s are syntactically incorrect, so this is query would not run.

Comment: Did adding `AND h.MARKET_VALUE<>0` not do the trick?

Comment: Doesn't that just need an additional predicate of `h.market_value != 0`? Also, why are you doing the `NVL(...., '')`? There is no such thing as an empty string in Oracle. What you're doing is the equivalent of saying "if <column> is null, then replace it with null", which doesn't really make any sense to do.

Comment: `TO_CHAR (h.DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = ? ` is concerning too. Why would you do that at all? Leave the date as it is, and use **TO_DATE** while comparing on the R.H.S.

Comment: When I said quantity, I meant the value of MARKET_VALUE

Comment: It would massively help us if you could provide example output from the above query and the output you actually would like.

Comment: It doesnt work MARKET_VALUE<>0 or  MARKET_VALUE!=0 because sometimes the market value is 0, and I don't have more values. Only I need the market value > 0 when I have two values and one of the them is 0. So I need to eliminate this one, and to obtain only the other.

Comment: I put an output below

Answer (score 0):

> How can I modify the query to get only the market value with quantity and not the quantity 0 ?

That is pretty straight and simple in SQL.

```
market_value > 0
```

You need **NVL** only when you have NULL values.

```
NVL(market_value, 0) > 0
```

There are multiple other issues with your code:

> TO_CHAR (h.DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = ?

Never use **TO_CHAR** to compare dates. The correct way is to let the date column as it is, and use **TO_DATE** on the R.H.S. to convert the literal into **DATE**.

With your query, you will end up comparing a **STRING** with whatever data type you have for the value in the place holder of `?`. However, you should leave the **DATE data type** as it is while comparing with dates.

> AND NVL (h.TYPE, '') NOT IN 'Master'
>
> AND NVL (h.INSTRUMENT, '') NOT IN 'FX'

That is syntactically incorrect. **IN** and **NOT IN** expression must be enclosed within **parenthesis**.

In fact, in your case, you don't need the **IN** operator at all. Just use **EQUAL** `=` operator.

> AND NVL (h.TYPE, '')

Another problem,

In Oracle, `''` and `NULL` are considered similar. That means, a zero length string is treated as NULL value.

So, your expression is just like saying, *consider NULL as NULL to compare with a real value. Which will always be FALSE*.

**UPDATE**

Based on OP's new update as shown below:

> The output I have now is :
>
> ```
> ID_CLIENT   CLIENT  NAME    MARKET_VALUE
> 207        Momentum AAA 0
> 207        Momentum AAA 3514.11
> 207        Momentum BBB 0
> 207        Momentum CCC 84289.84
> ```
>
> And what I want is:
>
> ```
> ID_CLIENT   CLIENT  NAME    MARKET_VALUE
> 207        Momentum AAA 3514.11
> 207        Momentum BBB 0
> 207        Momentum CCC 84289.84
> ```

You just need to use **MAX** as an aggregate function along with **GROUP BY**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But If I have 2 non-zero market_value rows per group, I need to keep both. I have edited the question and I put new output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look around at the other rows and throw away a zero market value if and only if another row doesn't exist:

```
with q as (
    SELECT p.ID_CLIENT, p.CLIENT, p.NAME, h.MARKET_VALUE
    FROM HOLDING h
    INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO p ON h.PF_ID = p.PF_ID 
    WHERE /* I'll let you fix this part */
        TO_CHAR (h.DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = ? 
        AND NVL (p.PF_ID, '') = ? 
        AND NVL (h.TYPE, '') NOT IN 'Master'
        AND NVL (h.INSTRUMENT, '') NOT IN 'FX'
)
select * from q
where MARKET_VALUE <> 0 or not exists (
    select 1 from q q2
    where /* I'm not entirely sure if this is your primary key */
            q2.ID_VALUE = q1.ID_VALUE
        and q2.CLIENT = q1.CLIENT
        and q2.NAME = q.NAME
        and q2.MARKET_VALUE <> 0
)
```

I used not equal in the comparisons although I imagine that all your values are probably non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

So sounds like you need to work out if the max market value for each group is 0 or not, and then filter accordingly, something like:

```
with sample_data as (select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'AAA' name, 0 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'AAA' name, 3514.11 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'BBB' name, 0 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'CCC' name, 84289.84 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'CCC' name, 358.74 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'DDD' name, 8289.24 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'DDD' name, 38.76 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'DDD' name, 0 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'EEE' name, 0 market_value from dual union all
                     select 207 id_client, 'Momentum' client, 'EEE' name, 0 market_value from dual),
-- end of mimicking the results of your query
             res as (select id_client,
                            client,
                            name,
                            market_value,
                            max(market_value) over (partition by id_client, name) max_market_value
                     from   sample_data)
select id_client,
       client,
       name,
       market_value
from   res
where  max_market_value = 0
or     (max_market_value != 0 and market_value != 0);

 ID_CLIENT CLIENT   NAME MARKET_VALUE
---------- -------- ---- ------------
       207 Momentum AAA       3514.11
       207 Momentum BBB             0
       207 Momentum CCC      84289.84
       207 Momentum CCC        358.74
       207 Momentum DDD       8289.24
       207 Momentum DDD         38.76
       207 Momentum EEE             0
       207 Momentum EEE             0
```

This means your query would look something like:

```
select id_client,
       client,
       name,
       market_value
from   (select p.id_client,
               p.client,
               p.name,
               h.market_value,
               max(h.market_value) over (partition by p.id_client, p.name) max_market_value
        from   holding h
               inner join portfolio p on (h.pf_id = p.pf_id)
        where  h.date = to_date(:p_date_string, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        and    p.pf_id = :p_pf_id 
        and    nvl (h.type, '{NULL}') not in ('Master')
        and    nvl (h.instrument, '{NULL}') not in ('FX'))
where  max_market_value = 0
or     (max_market_value != 0 and market_value != 0);
```

N.B. As you can see from the results above, if there were multiple rows with a market value of 0, you'd see all of them; I assume this is ok?